# Lua: Problems with menu

Tags: menu, lua, coronasdk, image

Ok. So I am coding a Corona program, and in the book I have followed all the instructions to create a menu and create a new game scene. Problem is nothing happens when I put the code into the emulator or bluestacks android and press on the pictures nothing happens. Literally nothing, same with help button.

What have I done wrong? This is my code:

```
function loadGame(event)
if event.target.name == "playbutton" then
    transition.to(menuScreenGroup, {time = 0, alpha=0, onComplete = addGamescreen})
    playBtn:removeEventListener("tap", loadgame)
    end
end

function loadHelp(event)
if event.target.name == "helpbutton" then
    transition.to(menuScreenGroup, {time = 0, alpha=0, onComplete = addHelpScreen})
    helpBtn:removeEventListener("tap", loadHelp)
end
end

function addHelpScreen()
helpScreenGroup = display.newGroup()
helpScreen = display.newImage("helpScreen.png", 0, 0, true)
helpScreen.x = _W
helpScreen.y = _H

end

function addGameScreen()
background = display.newImage("bg.png", 0, 0, true)
background.x = _W
background.y = _Ys

paddle = display.newImage("paddle.png")
paddle.x = 160; paddle.y = 460;
paddle.name = "paddle"

ball = display.newImage("ball.png")
ball.x = 160; ball.y = 460;
ball.name = "ball"

scoreText = display.newText("Score:", 5, 2, "Arial", 14)
scoreText:setTextColor( 255, 255, 255, 255)
scoreNum = display.newText("0", 54, 2, "Arial", 14)
scoreNum:setTextColor( 255, 255, 255, 255)

levelText = display.newText("Level:", 420, 2, "Arial", 14)
levelText:setTextColor(255, 255, 255, 255)
levelNum = display.newText("1", 460, 2, "Arial", 14)
levelNum:setTextColor( 255, 255, 255, 255)

gameLevel1()

currentLevel = 1

bricks:toFront()
local numOfRows = 4
local numOfColumns = 4
local brickPlacement = {x = (_W) - (brickWidth * numOfColumns ) / 2 + 20, y = 50}
for row = 0, numOfRows - 1 do
local brick = display.newImage("brick.png")
brick.name = "brick"
brick.x = brickPlacement.x + (column * brickWidth)
brick.y = brickPlacement.y + (row * brickHeight)
physics.addBody(brick, "static", {density = 1, friction = 0, bounce = 0})
bricks.insert(bricks, brick)

end
end

function gameLevel2()
currentLevel = 2
bricks:toFront()
local numOfRows = 5
local numOfColumns = 8
local brickPlacement = {x = (_W) - (brickWidth * numOfColumns ) / 2 + 20, y = 50}
for row = 0, numOfRows -  1 do
for column = 0, numOfColumns - 1 do
-- Create a brick
local brick = display.newImage("brick.png")
brick.name = "brick"
brick.x = brickPlacement.x + (column * brickWidth)
brick.y = brickPlacement.y + (row * brickHeight)
physics.addBody(brick, "static", {density = 1, friction = 0, bounce = 0})
bricks.insert(bricks, brick)
end
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this line of code:

```
background.y = _Ys
```

I think it should be:

```
background.y = _H
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you are adding any event listener to capture touches or taps.  I see where you are removing the tap handler.

Try doing:

somegraphic:addEventListener("tap",loadHelp)

I just can't tell from your code what you need to attach the event listener to though.

Answer (score 0):

Could you describe more about what do you want? Show me your code with addEventListener and do some print stuff in all the listener. So you can trace where is the exact problem.